# Point of using 4G enabled Nexus tablet in the USA

Tags: nexus-7, tablet, google, 4g

As far as I know, the providers (AT&T, Verizon, TMobile) in the USA neither sell nor support mobile connection for Nexus tablets. So what is the point of buying a Nexus tablet with 4G support in the USA?

Comment: AT&T and T-Mobile both offer data-only plans. You can even [buy the N7 from Google Play with a T-Mobile SIM included](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details/Nexus_7_32GB_Black_Wi_Fi_Mobile_data_Unlocked_T_Mo?id=nexus_7_32gb_2013_lte_tmo). Why are you under the impression that they can't be used? Where did you see any information that makes this claim?

Comment: @eldarerathis: In the link below, I do not see any SIM card for Nexus. This is link is for the case when we have the tablet already. http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/byop.html

Comment: AT&T's site has various SIMs labelled for popular devices and/or devices they sell themselves on that list, but they're not actually different. The "tablet" section shows 8 SIM cards, but look at the pictures. There are only two varieties there, which can be identified by their shape/size: mini SIM and micro SIM. The N7 takes a micro SIM. The fact that they chose to label their SIMs like that doesn't mean that the network only supports those 8 devices. If you filter the full shop to SIMs you can see them with more generic (accurate) labeling: http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/att.html

Comment: For example, here's their "SIM for 4G LTE Android and Windows Phone devices" (i.e a micro SIM): http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/att/att-sim-for-4g-lte-android-windows-devices.html